# Post jquery/ajax data to hidden field

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery/ajax geolocation script that outputs data such as:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').html(location.country_name);
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to get it to include that in a php form in a hidden field when the rest of the form is submitted. But so far I can't seem to get the geolocation script's data to submit with the form.

The important bit from the php form handler would be:

```
Country: " . $_POST['field_7'] . "
```

And in the html form I've tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_7" id="#country" value=''>
```

And various other things like `value="$('#country')"` but the geolocation data is not being posted/emailed with the form. How can I get the data the geolocation script captures to post to the hidden input in the form?

Comment: The `#` in jquery means `id=`, so you don't want the `#` in your id, change `<input type="hidden" name="field_7" id="#country" value=''>` to `<input type="hidden" name="field_7" id="country" value=''>`.  And then set with `$("#country").val(location.country_name);`  - **edit**: as someone answered.

Comment: `$('#\\#country').val(location.country_name);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove # from your input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_7" id="country" value=''>
```

And then in your JS, replace `html` with `val`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( location ) {
        $('#country').val(location.country_name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Original answer, and nice that you described the two issues.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks. Yes, I can see `html` is for printing to the page now. `val` for a form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').val(location.country_name);
        }
    });


<input type="hidden" name="field_7" id="country" value=''>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks. i wrote a short answer to answer quickly

Comment: yes, but a short description would improve it drastically (and may have got you marked as the answer).

Answer (score 1):

you just need to small change

write `val` instead of `html`

```
$('#country').val(location.country_name); // use val
```

and in html

Remove # from your input field id.